# Check if something was processed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

*The solution needs to work at least in Chrome.* I would like to detect when a document is ready. But wait, is not only verify the `document.readyStatus` or `document.onreadystatechange`.

When I use XMLHttpRequest, for instance, the page is "processing" something. And I need get the exact moment when this process end and trigger a callback. The problem is that I don't have access to XMLHttpRequest implementation code. I can only check the document status, for instance.

So, for instance, if on page had 4 XMLHttpRequest running, and 3 had end, nothing have, yet. But after the last one stop to process, my callback is triggered.

Comment: What? Are you talking about the main document or an XHR request?

Comment: About XHR, but I compared the *feature* to main document. But, basically, I need trigger a callback when all XHR is processed, and run it again if new is started and processed again.

Comment: Are the XHR's triggered by your code (or a 3rd party library for example) ?

Comment: 3rd party, and *read-only*. Because of leak of `unsafeWindow` to Chrome Extensions I can't handle it directly.

Comment: Then I don't know of any (reliable way) of doing it :(

Comment: Anyway, many thanks for the attempt. :)

Comment: You would use a content script and you csn use javascript Promises to detect when all requests finish. But the problem is all requests need to be initiated together otherwise how would you know the page wont start a new request?